# Why do I get NullException?

Tags: c#, exception, null

I searched a while and found no solution or do I just not see the little error?

I wrote a program with Visual C# and have 
Form1.cs
Program.cs
Server.cs

Server.cs

---

```
namespace WindowsApplication1 {
class testServer {
public Form1 form1;
form1.send("data");
```

Program.cs

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication1 
{
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
}
```

Form1.cs

---

```
namespace WindowsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private testServer Server;

private void startServer_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        Server = new Server(data);
        Server.form1 = this;

    }
```

Everything works but in Server.cs I get a nullexception with `form1.send("data");`
It seems form1 is really null but why?

Where did I forget something?

Comment: `form1.send("data");` is not inside of a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create an instance of Form1, try

```
public Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

Comment: ok, that helped me to continue =) thanks. thought it was already done there.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Form1 form1;
form1.send("data");
```

form1 is never instantiated. There is your NullReferenceException (NRE).

Better:

```
public Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.send("data");
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to assign the `form1` variable in `testServer` to the construct parameter.

BTW: You code doesn't look like good design: You shouldn't pass Form objects around.

Answer (score 1):

It is null because you're not initializing it.

```
public Form1 form1;
..
// Initialize the object BEFORE using it!
form1 = new Form1();
form1.send("data");
```

Comment: "WindowsApplication1.SocketServer.form1" is not a Field, but is used ...
This method has to have a return type or something like this

Answer (score 0):

The `form1` variable is not initialised before being used in the code